# How to vertically align an image in a container that fills the page?

Tags: html, css, centering

I'm working on creating an image gallery where an image is centered in the entire page. The horizontal part is of course easy, but the vertical part is giving trouble.

I'm familiar with using `display: table-cell;` and `vertical-align: middle;` (or using `line-height`, but am not having success when using them along with trying to get the element to fill the page.

```
<div id='contain'>
   <img src='url' />
</div>
```

I can't set the line-height of `#contain` since the height of the container will vary based on the size of the window.

If I absolutely position `#contain`, applying `vertical-align:middle` no longer centers the image vertically, regardless of how I set the size of the box.

If I try to size `#contain` to fill the window without absolute positioning, `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` (or using min-width/min-height) do not fill the page. Again, I can't specify exact values since they'll vary.

I know I can always set the image to be the background of `#contain` (or use JavaScript to figure out the heights), but if there's a CSS/HTML way of solving this without tables I'd prefer to use that.

Comment: try setting `vertical-align` to the `<img>` not `#contain`

Comment: Hey, sometimes I find the height of the `<body>` and `<html>` tags need to be set as well, or this sort of thing won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap your img in an extra div and then use the following css:

```
#contain {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#contain div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='contain'>
   <div><img src='url' /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This would probably work, but the heights/widths of the images do vary and so I'd have to add in a few extra lines to adjust for that. I was hoping to find a universal solution if it exists.